# How to put pylab.plot line over pylab.figtext?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want the plot line to overlay the text. Here is current code:

```
pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1], color='red', lw=3, label='Temp' )
pylab.figtext(0.7, 0.5, round(temp1,2), color='white', fontsize=450,
    bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'alpha':0.8, 'pad':12})
```

I'm using very large white digits and the red plot line is hidden by these digits. I simply want the plot line to be on top of the digits. I tried adding alpha=0.2 to the figtext line and then I could see the plot line but both the white digit and plot line looked dim.

Comment: Why not use `annotate` or `text` that are axes artist instead of `figtext` which is a figure-level artist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `zorder` kwarg to control what crosses what.

By default, text has a higher `zorder` than lines, images, and other plot features (the idea being that text is usually a label that should be on top).

However, there's an additional wrinkle.  You're currently using `figtext`.  This places the text at the figure level instead of at the axes level.  You'll need to use `plt.text`/`ax.text` instead.  If you'd like to specify the position in figure coordinates as you currently are, you can pass in `transform=fig.transFigure`.

Here's an example of the way things would look by default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(10), color='red', lw=3)
# Placing the text in data coordinates...
ax.text(5, 5, 'Test', color='white', fontsize=45,
        bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'pad':12})

plt.show()
```

[image]

And here's what happens when we change the `zorder` (the default for text is 3, if I recall correctly.  Any `zorder` greater than or equal to 4 overlay any text objects in the plot.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(10), color='red', lw=3, zorder=4)
# Placing the text in data coordinates...
ax.text(5, 5, 'Test', color='white', fontsize=45,
        bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'pad':12})

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, if we use `plt.figtext` or `fig.text` (they're identical), the text will be placed at the figure level instead of at the axes level.  Therefore, it doesn't matter what the `zorder` of the line is, the text will still be in front of anything in the axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(10), color='red', lw=3, zorder=5000)
# Placing the text in figure coordinates
fig.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Test', color='white', fontsize=45,
        bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'pad':12})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Therefore, if you want to use figure coordinates and still have the line be on top, you should use `ax.text` or `ax.annotate` and specify `transform=fig.transFigure` so that the coordinates you use are interpreted as figure fractions:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(range(10), color='red', lw=3, zorder=4)
# Placing the text in figure coordinates
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Test', color='white', fontsize=45, transform=fig.transFigure,
        bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'pad':12})

plt.show()
```

[image]